# Solving a Linear Functional

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

> Solve the Euler's equation for the functional:
>
> $$J[y]=\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{x}dx$$
>
> with $y(1)=0$ and $y(2)=1$

This would be the automatic approach:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$

which gives

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2y'}{2x\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=0$$

$$\frac{y'}{x\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=C$$

$$y'=Cx\sqrt{1+y'^2}$$

$$y'^2=Cx^2+cx^2y'^2$$

$$y'^2-Cx^2y'^2=Cx^2$$

$$y'^2=\frac{Cx^2}{1-Cx^2}$$

$$y'=\frac{\sqrt{C}x}{\sqrt{1-Cx^2}}$$

Integration gives

$$y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{1-Cx^2}}{\sqrt{C}}+D$$

Then we rearrange:

$$y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{1-Cx^2}}{\sqrt{C}}+D$$

$$y-D=-\frac{\sqrt{1-Cx^2}}{\sqrt{C}}$$

$$(y-D)^2=\frac{1}{C}-x^2$$

$$(y-D)^2+x^2=\frac{1}{C}$$

Insert for initial condition 1:

$$(D)^2+1^2=\frac{1}{C}\longrightarrow D=\sqrt{1/C-1}$$

Insert for initial condition 2:

$$(1-D)^2+2^2=\frac{1}{C}\longrightarrow D=1-\sqrt{1/C-4}$$

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Not really, because I am looking for an alternative formula for that functional.  Besides, I recall the solution to this integral is transformed over to a radial system, and solved on the disk $x^2+y^2\le R$. But I can't find out how.

Comment: What do you mean, “this ends nowhere?” You have solved the differential equation. Just put in your boundary conditions

Comment: @FShrike Give it Try! I can't solve that. I get $$6C=2+\sqrt{1-C}\sqrt{1-4C}$$. Neither can Wolfram

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Wolfram can definitely solve that equation given the right input. It’s just a quadratic. $(6C-2)^2=(1-C)(1-4C)$

Comment: @FShrike great, but "by hand" ? Besides, the solution to this is complex, and it does not make any sense as the problem is in physics terms to find the arc length on a real  coordinate system. So the whole question is not solved by this. In fact, I don't understand it. This is why I wonder if the original formula $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$ is an inappropriate choice for this problem.

Comment: I’m assuming you’ve correctly solved the ODE and have correctly plugged in boundary equations. If you’ve done that, then this quadratic should give the correct result, and quadratics are *always* doable by hand without too much trouble.

Comment: Why do you assume that, when the question is still unanswered and I am still posting updates?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz what is explicitly the original ODE you are trying to solve?

Comment: @student91 look at the top

Comment: What is "the Euler's equation" in this context I mean

Comment: Still given at the top!

Comment: Going from $y'=Cx\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ to $y'^2=Cx^2+cx^2y'^2$ you forgot to square $C$ (and you typed a small $c$ instead of $C$). The solution is $y=2-\sqrt{5-x^2}.$ I do not understand what kind of "alternative formula" you are looking for, and I am not aware of what you "recall" ("the solution to this integral is transformed over to a radial system, and solved on the disk $x^2+y^2≤R$"). Is it just $x^2+(y-2)^2=5$ that you wanted?

Comment: Or is it that once you know the solution $y,$ you are not able to calculate $J[y]?$

Comment: Anne, how did you get that ? $y=2-\sqrt{5-x^2}$. Your answer is the correct one.

Comment: If it is because I forgot to square C, why would that matter, when it is still a "C"? I could say $C^2=D$